# Drupal 10 Pantheon.io "DB Error: unknown error" on Event Registration in Test or Live Sites

Tags: civievent, drupal, error, pantheon

I am working on getting Drupal 10 / CiviCRM working on Pantheon.io. I am close to get CiviCRM properly running but have run into an issue where event registration creates unknown database error on test and live (but works on dev).

The error message is "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: unknown error"

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create Pantheon.io site, spin up and install Drupal 10 as usual
2. Copy locally with git or "terminus local:clone SITENAME"
3. In cloned folder Run "composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}" then "composer require civicrm/cli-tools"
4. Edit the json to whitelist compiling. Under ""enable-patching": true" add the line ""compile-whitelist": ["civicrm/civicrm-core", "civicrm/composer-compile-lib"]"
5. Push your changes with "git add ." then "git commit -m 'adding civicrm'" and "git push"
6. Change the Pantheon Development site to SFTP
7. On Pantheon site go to YOURDOMAIN.COM/admin/modules and enable "CiviCRM Core". It will create the settings.civicrm.php file. Check to make sure it worked. (At this point it only works on the dev instance)
8. Commit that file to Git on Pantheon.
9. Pull down the code "git pull" to your local.
10. Run "wget -O pantheon.civicrm.settings.local.php [https://gist.github.com/herbdool/baec130982e3995b5577008f1a63ebd9"](https://gist.github.com/herbdool/baec130982e3995b5577008f1a63ebd9%22) (see: https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_starterkit/issues/3095528)
11. Follow instructions in pantheon.civicrm.settings.local.php to update keys and insert code in civicrm.settings.php
12. Push code to pantheon (test by creating a CIVICRM event and registering on dev site, it works)
13. Clone to test environment (test by creating event and registering on test site, it results in DB error)

This is when the browser, in a yellow box, displays " Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: unknown error"

The logs show a number of warnings, it is unclear to me if this is the best line of investigations but seem to be of possible interest:

Warning: Undefined array key "fee"

Warning: Undefined array key "elemType"

Warning: Undefined array key "hideBlocks"

Warning: Undefined array key "showBlocks"

Warning: Undefined array key "confirm_footer_text"

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Warning: Undefined array key "addParticipantProfile"

Warning: Undefined array key "CustomPost"

Warning: Undefined array key "pcpBlock"

Warning: Undefined array key "confirm_text"

Warning: Undefined array key "priceSet"

Warning: Undefined array key "participantListingURL"

Warning: Undefined array key "participant_fee_currency"

Warning: Undefined array key "participant_fee_amount"

Warning: Undefined array key "participant_fee_level"

Warning: Undefined array key "description"

Warning: Undefined array key "summary"

Has anyone encountered a similar 'DB Error: unknown error' during CiviCRM event registration in Drupal 10 on Pantheon (or elsewhere)? The process works on the dev environment but fails on the test environment, suggesting a possible configuration or environmental issue. I have been trying to figure out if this can be resolved by changes to the civicrm.settings.php configuration file without luck. Any suggestions for troubleshooting or resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Also posted to: https://community.pantheon.io/forum/t/civicrm-drupal-10-db-error-unknown-error-on-event-registration-in-test-or-live-sites/167